# Programatically set communication between android/ pc app through internet

Tags: android, client-server

I'd like to let my android app interact with another on the pc side, through wifi or ethernet.
I already made my android device connected to the local network through wifi or ethernet.
But I dont know how to let those app detect each other and do communications.
I've read the training tutorial on developer.android.com but all there are depends on API16. But I'm using a 2.3.3 API10.

Can anyone show me how to do this and where I can find the related tutorial. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to consider developing in C#, i.e. xamarin.android, you could look at using a compatible network library to save some time. If so checkout [NetworkComms.Net](http://www.networkcomms.net).

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for this library.